# Dilemma about how my wireless devices obtain IP address

Tags: ipv4, networking, dhcp, isp

Currently in my network there are 7 wireless outdoor equipment and 1 switch . This switch act as backbone switch for my network as internet supply from ISP is connected to this switch. Through this switch 7 wireless outdoor equipment and Personal computer are connected. These wireless outdoor is not connected to the router instead these outdoor solely serves as wireless network. There is no DHCP server in this network and I am unaware whether there is dhcp server in these outdoor. My ISP says  they have given 252 IP address.

I have confusion on the following point:-

->If there is dhcp server on these outdoor then how does wirelessly connected devices obtain   IP address (from pool of 252 IP address or dhcp server from Wireless outdoor) ?

-> If these outdoor devices have dhcp server then how many host can be connected to this entire network

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you know, you can only have one DHCP service in a LAN, so if your ISP router is serving DHCP all of your devices are obtaining IPs from it. Are you sure your wireless outdoor is not connected to the router (gateway pointing to router's LAN IP)?

Comment: @Santeador it isn't connected to any of the router. Moreover there is not a router at all in this network

Comment: I understand that ISP is serving DHCP, so any device that you connect to the switch is requesting DHCP to your ISP. If your Wireless is connected to the switch, it is also requesting DHCP. I'm sorry, maybe a little schema of your LAN will be helpful...

Comment: Schema of DHCP request:

Client ask for an IP to his gateway. If the device got DHCP server it will serve an IP to the client, if not it will send the request to his own gateway.

In your LAN: Client - Wifi AP - Switch - ISP (DHCP server).